# How to change label format, distance between main text and plot, and put the number on the each parts?

Tags: r, plotrix

I plot a pie chart but get some questions on how to modify it.
My code is

```
library(plotrix)
df <- c(29, 29, 36,26)
lbls <- c("Blue(29)","Gold(29)","Green(36)","Orange(26)")
labelco <- c('Blue','yellow','springgreen3','darkorange1')
pie3D(df, main="Yi Li's Color", labels=lbls, radius=0.5, 
      col = labelco ,labelrad=1.7,
      explode=0.1)
```

and you can get a pie chart below:
[pie chart I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoZbF.jpg)

Is anyone can teach me:
how to change label format(maybe choose Times New Roman), distance between main text and plot, and put the number on the each parts ?
Thank you very much.
Best Regards,

Comment: I have not come across the `plotrix` library before, so I don't know about that, but you can make all the modifications you specified if you use `ggplot2` instead. Reference: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_polar.html

Comment: Hi @Teja K, I am new R user. Can you show the code to me ? So I need how to do it for next time. Thank you much.

Comment: The link I posted above shows how to build a pie chart using `ggplot2`. If you're looking for things like changing font, there are tons of resources. If you just do a google search, you will find lots of questions on stackoverflow, so it isn't very hard!